# How can I get the sum of numbers being clicked in function?

Tags: javascript

I keep receiving just the new number, no sum. While I see what the problem is- I'm unable to figure out how to fix it.
This is my code:

```
<script>
  let temp = `<Table border = 1>`;
  for (let row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
    temp += `<tr>`;
    for (let cols = 1; cols <= 10; cols++) {
      temp += `<td style='(${row * cols},
                 ${row * cols}, ${row * cols})'> ${row * cols} </td>`;
    }
  }
  temp += "</Tr>";
  temp += `</table> `;
  multiBoard.innerHTML = temp;

  function sumNums() {
    let sum = event.target.innerText;
    let saveSum = "";
    saveSum += sum;
    console.log(saveSum);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `sumNums`.

Comment: Try `saveSum += +sum;` in `sumNums` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. You declare `saveSum` as a string when it should be an integer. Change it to `let saveSum = 0;`
2. You should declare the `saveSum` variable globally (outside of the `sumNums` function)
3. I assume you're calling the function from HTML, but if not that needs to be addressed as well.
4. Update the `sum` declaration to `let sum = parseInt(event.target.innerText);` to make sure you're performing addition rather than string concatenation.

Comment: For some reason it's still seeing it as a string, and just adding the 0 at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Ah, since you're adding the inner text of an element, you have to parse that text to an integer. Try updating the `sum` declaration to `let sum = parseInt(event.target.innerText);`

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script>
  let temp = `<Table border = 1>`;
  let saveSum = 0;
  for (let row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
    temp += `<tr>`;
    for (let cols = 1; cols <= 10; cols++) {
      temp += `<td style='(${row * cols},
                 ${row * cols}, ${row * cols})'> ${row * cols} </td>`;
    }
  }
  temp += "</Tr>";
  temp += `</table> `;
  multiBoard.innerHTML = temp;

  function sumNums() {
    let sum = event.target.innerText;
    saveSum += Number(sum);
    console.log(saveSum);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What have you changed ?

Comment: Ok, that's definetly a step forward, thanks! But it's not giving me the sum, it's just putting the numbers together. (=instead of 4+5 being 9, I'm getting 45)

Comment: try again. You and I were declaring saveSum as a string. You have to declare it as follows.
let saveSum = 0.

Comment: For some reason it's still seeing it as a string, and just adding the 0 at the beginning of the string.

Comment: convert your sum variable into a Number like this Number(sum) because the value you are getting from event.target.innerText is in string. So save the sum like this in the saveSum variable like this.  
saveSum += Number(sum)